# SwiftUI HStack clipping subviews

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack

I am trying to implement a video scrubber/trimmer in SwiftUI. To do this, put image thumbnails in an HStack as follows:

```
struct ThumbnailsView: View {
  @State private var thumbImages:[ThumbImage] = []

   var body: some View {
      HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
          ForEach(thumbImages, id: \.time) { thumbImage in
              Image(uiImage: thumbImage.image)
                  .border(Color.white, width: 5)
           }
           .padding(5)
       }
       
    }
 }

 struct ThumbImage {
   var time: CMTime
   let image: UIImage
 }
```

This should basically allow to construct series of images in the scrubber/trimmer (like in Photos app). However, my requirement (which is different from behavior in Photos app) is that as user trims from either end, the trimmer gets shortened and clips the leftmost(or rightmost depending on direction of trim) thumbnail by respective amount, so that only a fraction of the leftmost or rightmost thumbnail is shown as the user drags the end of the trimmer. I could do it in UIKit but just want to understand how this can be done in SwiftUI.

[image]

Comment: Why not just do it in UIKit? You keep asking questions about trying to mimic UIKit but SwiftUI is very different, it takes a change in mindset. But you haven’t shown what you have tried or what is/isnt working. Other then writing an entire program for you there is no way to help you with your issue.

Comment: *Who on Earth is downvoting this and for what?* It wasn't me. But I would guess the downvote is because there is not enough information in the post for anyone to be able to help you with debugging the problem. You've provided a snippet of code, but it's not much more than a `ForEach` block. I would suggest, you need to show the context for how this `View` is being used. The best way is to provide a *minimal reproducible example* that other developers can drop straight into an empty XCode project. Some screenshots to illustrate the problem and the actual required behavior might help too.

Comment: @BenzyNeez Honestly I have no idea how to move forward from this code. No one needs to write code for me, but just tell how you can have clipped subviews in HStack in SwiftUI. That is enough to answer the question. I will post a gif if someone still needs info.

Comment: @loremipsum I am still struggling to figure out what can actually be done in SwiftUI and what not vis-a-vis UIKit. I have done lot of things with UIKit in the past 13 years and I can say it takes the most time consuming part of the app vis-a-vis other parts. I have found SwiftUI useful and quick to build UI. Only thing is I need to know it's limitations.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I have added a GIF in the question.

Comment: *I have no idea how to move forward from this code* So the gif helps to show what you want to achieve, but the code snippet doesn't go very far towards achieving it (it doesn't even contain an `HStack`, despite the title). You could try using an `HStack(spacing: 0)` as the container for the `ForEach` and give it a fixed width, computed from the clip duration. Then use `.clipped()` for the trim effect you're after. If it needs to be scrollable then try putting it inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Sorry for missing `HStack(spacing:0)` in the code, I have updated the code in the question. For `clipped()`, you need to provide clip shape and set the dimensions. And the dimensions of that shape and/or `position` of the shape needs to be changed by the dragged amount. It seems at first one would need to embed the HStack in a `GeometryReader`, add a drag gesture to the view, and then manipulate `position` and size of the clip shape. Is that what needs to be done or there is an easier way out?

Comment: Also, if this trimmer is inside a `ScrollView` will clip shape change the content size of the `ScrollView` or the content size of the scroll view will still be the size of the unclipped view. How SwiftUI works in this case is the heart of the question.

Comment: SwiftUI IS for quick development, it is getting better but you will have to compromise in customizations. Quick development + maximum platform coverage are the priority. You have to remember that Apple has prioritized fitting all screens with one set of code including watchOS. Least constraints == maximum adaptability. As for this you just have to associate the image size with size of the interval it is representing. If the interval is 2.5 seconds then show have the image. Vis a vis is not a great way to tackle SwiftUI if you approach it like UIKit your views will not adapt to all screens.

Comment: A “model” tells SwiftUI what to do. It is rarely predetermined. Think in terms of % not points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick demo for what I think you are looking for.
It's gonna get a bit more complicated when inside a `ScollView`, but you have a starting point.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var timecode = 200.0
    @State private var dragAmount = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image("thumbnail")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                    Image("thumbnail")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 120) // this one is important
                }
                
            }
            .border(.blue)
            .frame(width: timecode + dragAmount, alignment: .leading)
            .clipped()
            
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 10, alignment: .leading)
                    .offset(x: timecode + dragAmount)
                
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            dragAmount = value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            timecode += value.translation.width
                            dragAmount = 0
                        }
                             , including: .gesture)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("timecode = \(timecode, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good starting point, though eventually it needs to be done in `ScrollView`? In UIKit, I first disable scrolling in `UIScrollView` when a pan gesture is detected and proceed with trimming. Is it the same in SwiftUI or a bit different?

Comment: The are numerous posts on SO about detecting a gesture inside `ScollView`. As I understand it should work with ` .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)`.

Comment: I am facing issues including the trimmer on left side as well. Should I update this question or ask separate one?

Answer (score 1):

As for your extended question ... the rest you might need to solve yourself:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var timecodeStart = 100.0
    @State private var dragAmountStart = 0.0
    @State private var timecodeEnd = 300.0
    @State private var dragAmountEnd = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image("thumbnail")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            
            Spacer()
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                            Image("thumbnail")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 120) // this one is important
                        }
                    }
                    .border(.blue)
                    .frame(width: timecodeEnd + dragAmountEnd - timecodeStart - dragAmountStart, alignment: .leading)
                    .offset(x: -timecodeStart - dragAmountStart)
                    .clipped()
                    
                    Color.black
                        .frame(width: 500, height: 68)
                }
                .offset(x: timecodeStart + dragAmountStart)

                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    // Front
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10, alignment: .leading)
                        .offset(x: timecodeStart + dragAmountStart)
                    
                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                dragAmountStart = value.translation.width
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                timecodeStart += value.translation.width
                                dragAmountStart = 0
                            }
                        )
                    
                    // End
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10, alignment: .leading)
                        .offset(x: timecodeEnd + dragAmountEnd)
                    
                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                dragAmountEnd = value.translation.width
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                timecodeEnd += value.translation.width
                                dragAmountEnd = 0
                            }
                        )

                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("from \(timecodeStart, specifier: "%.1f") to \(timecodeEnd, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer once again. I couldn't find stuff like this on SwiftUI anywhere. Most people were of opinion that SwiftUI is not apt for such timeline and UIKit is more appropriate but now we know that even Apple is making heavy use of SwiftUI in FCP and Logic Pro. It seems not so difficult to solve such problems with SwiftUI but the complexity may scale with more number of elements and layers in the timeline(similar to UIKit).